# How would you translate "新聞の民主性"?

Tags: translation

I'm working on a paper about media science and in one of the Japanese papers
the author talks about　"新聞の民主性". I do know the general meaning of the word, but I struggle to put it into proper English or struggle to find the corresponding English term.

Here's is one of the sentences for context:

井口の新聞学では、彼はマス・コミュニケーションの一つとして相対化され、同時に「新聞の民主性」というイデオロギーが成立した。

Comment: The democracy of newspapers.

Comment: @FriendlyGhost I'm on the "unanswered questions" tab trying to see if any of them can be resolved. Would you like to convert your comment to an answer here?

Answer (score 2):

........ 「新聞の民主性」というイデオロギーが成立した。

........ and established the ideology of "democratic nature of newspapers."

........ and led to the ideology of "newspapers as a democratizing force."

```
         イデオロギー could be idealism, philosophy, notion, ... depending on context.
```